# Moment.js open a file with different dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm using moment.js this way and it works.

```
var cutoffString = '2020-07-31T21:43:00.000Z'; // in utc
var utcCutoff = moment.utc(cutoffString, 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss');
var displayCutoff = utcCutoff.clone().tz('America/Los_Angeles');

console.log('utcCutoff:', utcCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ssa Z'));
console.log('displayCutoff:', displayCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ssa Z'));
```

Now I want moment.js open a file (dates.txt) with 3 different dates to convert. eg.

1. 2020-07-31T21:43:00.000Z
2. 2020-07-30T21:43:00.000Z
3. 2020-07-28T21:43:00.000Z

   and the 3 dates converted added to a newdates.txt file.

Can I do it with moment.js or other .js ?

Comment: You can read `dates.txt` line by line.

Comment: You can read/write a file content with `fs` module. `moment.js` can be used to convert the dates not for reading/writing a file. [Check here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-and-write-json-file-using-node-js) on how to read/write content of a file.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to open the dates.txt by `fs` package in NodeJS
2. Split lines by `\n` to get an array of dates
3. Write a `for loop` on every item of the array and do everything you want in each loop.
4. Done